# Tethering an Toshiba AT100 to a Nokia E71

Tags: tethering

I want to tether an Toshiba AT100 tablet to my Nokia E71. Have installed JuikoSpot on the Nokia which creates an ad-hoc hotspot. It appears the AT100 only looks for infrastructure hotspots. Is there an app or other method of getting the AT100 to look for and connect to an ad-hoc hotspot?

Alternatively, is there a cheap Android phone I could get that supports being an infrastructure wi-fi hotspot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try bluetooth tethering instead.

**Benefits**: Consumes less power, you can leave bluetooth enabled 24/7. Works out of the box.
**Drawback**: BT 2.1 may cap your maximum UMTS speed (usually not an issue on the go).

[image: Bluetooth pairing to a Nokia from a Nexus S running 4.0.4]

There are two profiles for this to tether via bluetooth:

- Bluetooth PAN:
  Supported by Android 3.0+ out of the box. See Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Personal_Area_Networking_Profile_.28PAN.29) for more info on PAN profile.
- Bluetooth DUN:
  Needs 3rd party app like [BlueVPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluevpn) (ICS version [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluexvpn)). See Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Dial-up_Networking_Profile_.28DUN.29) for more info on DUN profile.

Stock Android 3.0+ and custom roms like CM should support Bluetooth PAN. Your Nokia E71 supports only DUN profile ([Archos](http://wiki.archosfans.com/index.php?title=Bluetooth_tethering_phones_tested_to_work) users can enjoy added DUN support out of the box however) .

Comment: I have paired my tablet and phone but they will not connect to each other.

Comment: does it show 'internet access' on your at100?

Comment: No. It says "Paired but not connected" in the bluetooth settings against my phone. There doesn't seem to be any other options.

Comment: Can you try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluevpn or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluexvpn (Seems I missed an important part: Android needs an app for DUN client and E71 and other older Nokias don't support bluetooth PAN profile)

Comment: I have installed BlueVPN and inserted the settings as the instructions state. It gets stuck at the "Opening VPN" step. I must have missed a setting or something, probably in the phone or for the Access Point (Telstra Australia).

Comment: Yes, it's a missing setting: APN for Telstra data plan. Sadly you have to know this (by looking at your e71 settings). See more details at http://bluedunapp.blogspot.de/2012/06/bluevpn-connect-your-android-device-to.html?m=1 . If all that doesnt work and, :-) yeah, you still don't give up by frustration we can meet in chat and I'll try to help you there. Besides this: the developer is really responsive and helpful, got an answer within 5 mins last time i contacted him

Comment: Just got a responce saying the firmware on the AT100 (3.2.1) is not supporting the teathering feature. He recomended upgrading to ICS, not sure if it is possible on this tablet.

Comment: Have finally managed to get the tablet connected to the internet, but it involved buying a Samsung Nexux S (upgraded to ICS) and using WiFi Hotspot.

Comment: Nice to know! Have you tried the bluetooth tether method yet? That's easier on the battery and you could leave bluetooth on 24/7. It's not as fast though, only 0.8Mbit/s real speed but thats sufficient for me most of the time