# TCP/IP tethering over Bluetooth

Tags: tethering, bluetooth-tethering, samsung-galaxy-player

I have a Samsung Galaxy Player 5.0 and I would like to browse the web over a bluetooth connection to my computer. I can connect to the computer but the browser doesn't have internet connectivity even though the computer does. Also, the Bluetooth standards indicate that this is supported.

Anyone ever have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth tethering in both(?) ways is supported from Android-4.0 ICS onwards.
Your device however runs Android 2.3.5+ and most likely will not support that feature out of the box.

As a second requirement you need your computer to *also* offer bluetooth-tethering via Bluetooth-NAP or Bluetooth-DUN protocol (you will need 3rd party software for that, see link below).

This question/answer also touches your concern: [Tethering an Toshiba AT100 to a Nokia E71](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24139/tethering-an-toshiba-at100-to-a-nokia-e71)