# Access Internet via Bluetooth from Windows 7 Desktop to Android 2.3.5 Mobile phone

Tags: bluetooth, internet, windows, reverse-tether

Hi need to know How do we Access Internet via Bluetooth from Windows 7 Desktop PC to Android 2.3.5 Mobile phone? Please advice step by step solution and Thanks in advance.

When I was raising this question, found "How to use PC internet on Android mobile via Bluetooth [duplicate] 1" but it don't have the complete step by step details.

Please guide.

Comment: That's called "reverse-tethering", and dealt with e.g. in [these questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[reverse-tether]+bluetooth). Especially see: [TCP/IP tethering over Bluetooth](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24332/16575).