# Bluetooth 3G modem

Tags: bluetooth, tethering, 3g, bluetooth-tethering

I have a Nokia 6500S-1 which I previously used as a 3G modem (with Windows). Is it possible for an Android device to use this phone as a modem (just like the windows PC does), but expose the modem functionality thru *bluetooth* instead of USB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your phone supports two ways to export its internet connection via bluetooth:

- DUN-GW (Dial-Up Networking Gateway)
- PAN-AP (Personal Area Networking Access Point)

See also [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24139/tethering-an-toshiba-at100-to-a-nokia-e71) question (its answer about bluetooth).

In short: PAN is supported from Android 3.0 onwards as client. Android <3.0 users may have luck with [Wireless tether for root users](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.tether). DUN is not supported out of the box, there are [apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=bluetooth+dun+client) though. Go for PAN if it works for you (DUN requires parameter and possibly eats more battery).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try it first thing in the morning.