# Using a wifi dongle to monitor network

Tags: wi-fi, linux, kernel, usb-drivers

I have an android smart box with a built-in wifi and I want to add a dongle to the box so that I can monitor the network. I have found a similar question with somewhat vague answer(at least to me); 
[Android as WiFi bridge with AP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37141/android-as-wifi-bridge-with-ap)

I have 3 wifi dongles at the moment. The device can detect 2 of them(with dmesg run from shell and also a small android application which gets vendorId and productId of the connected usb devices) but I don't know if the required drivers are installed or modules are loaded.

My question is if the devices are detected, can i make use of them in an android app? or do I have to download android source code and compile it with new drivers/modules?

Basically I'm a little bit stuck and any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean, "so that I can monitor the network"? I don't see what a second Wi-Fi network would help you do.

Comment: I mean I want to get info about the surrounding wifi devices like signal strength mac address etc.(with a dongle) and still be able to communicate with other devices over wifi(with the built-in wifi). I could give an example if it is still not clear.

Comment: OK, you should [edit] your question to add that information. Also, you should say what device you have, and what Wi-Fi dongles you're trying to use. **Some** Android devices support **some** Wi-Fi dongles; if you name the particular devices, you might get a more specific answer from someone who has the same.

Comment: Specific devices have nothing to do with my question. But if it led you to believe to i think the question may be a bit vague so i edited it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built-in Wi-Fi, and use a network monitor tool like [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en)?

Comment: Built-in wifi will be used for communicating with other devices **on** the network while the dongle will look for other devices **without being connected** to a network so it can monitor every device in range.