# Tethering internet over WiFi

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering

Consider I am using a WiFi hotspot (authenticated with password) for internet on my mobile. Is it possible to tether the connection to another device via any WiFi, USB, or Bluetooth?

Let me be clear for example I have a **WiFi** modem through which I **can access the internet** on my phone, now my question is now whether I can tether my mobile **WiFi/USB/Bluetooth** so that I can provide **connection to another people**. (here internet source is WiFi modem)

[image]

Is there an option? Also, whenever I enable WiFi portability, the current connection gets disconnected.

Comment: [How to use Android in Wi-Fi repeater mode by bridging Wi-Fi with Access Point?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202336/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can share your phone's WiFi connection which is connected via any WiFi source to more phones, tablets, and computers using Bluetooth so other devices can access the internet. Here's how to share your Android phone's WiFi connection over Bluetooth.

http://www.androidpit.com/share-wifi-over-bluetooth

Comment: well, but if you have a connection which shares wifi then you can connect other device too using same wifi :-). why a longer path

Comment: :) yes it is longer but my friends mobile is not authenticated to main wifi modem..

Answer (score 0):

The tethering option or hotspot is available only if you are connected to a mobile data/carrier network. If you are already connected to WiFi, enabling hotspot on your phone will disconnect you from the WiFi. This is a limitation in all Android phones.

Comment: thank you @bbh ,usb ,bluetooth tethering too get disconnected ?

Comment: Tethering will not disconnect Bluetooth. But I am not sure about USB, but my guess is USB should not be disconnected.

Comment: so other mobile can access internet ?

Comment: @bbh I think he is trying to use the 1st connected device as wifi extender

Answer (score 0):

From the picture I understand that you want to make a **repeater** with your phone? Is that correct?

1. The phone must be have ROOT access.
2. Install the application (**fqrouter2-2-12-7-multi-android.apk**) or (**fqrouter-2.11.5.apk**)
3. Make the settings and enjoy ...

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are few devices that can work as a WiFi bridge, i.e can use WiFi and share the internet of that WiFi through a hotspot simultaneously. Redmi Note 5 Pro is an example of it. You can share the WiFi through USB tethering.