# Is it possible to visit a localhost page of my pc on Android without wifi route?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I don't have a wifi router.  I want to visit xampp localhost from my mobile. I have two android phone.  Is it possible with any app to use a phone like wifi router and another phone to visit the localhost pages?

Comment: You have already tagged WiFi hotspot. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I assume you mean router in the headline? It ends with wifi route, which is something different.

Comment: @IrfanLatif There are multiple possibilities, and choosing one is the question.

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [How to use Android in Wi-Fi repeater mode by bridging Wi-Fi with Access Point?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37141/44325)

Comment: Servers on Localhost will never be available from outside of your PC no matter how many routes you set or connections you add. The only way is to make the server listen on all IPs or use the USB connection to the device and install a port forwarding for the server port via `adb` from the PC to the device.

Answer (score -1):

You do have a hotspot available!

You can **configure your own phone as WiFi hotspot**, and connect to it from the PC!