# how to convert android 10 phone to a software access point

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, android-10

I have an android 10 device which I would like to use use as software access point. I have broadband connection landline in my home. There are some corners where signals dont reach. So I want to use my spare android phone to convert it to a software access point. If this is some how possible then please let me know. I want my phone to be connected to the exisiting wifi network at a location in which signal is comming and at the same time want to convert the phone to work as an AP.
The phone is already connected to Wifi network in my ADSL router.

Comment: What you describe is not an access point but a Wifi repeater.

Comment: For rooted device see my answer to [How to use Android in Wi-Fi repeater mode by bridging Wi-Fi with Access Point?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37141/how-to-use-android-in-wi-fi-repeater-mode-by-bridging-wi-fi-with-access-point). Without root some WiFi Direct based solution may work, never tried though.